# Is there a way to save the parent selector ($) as a variable in SCSS?

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to make it so when any children of a dropdown menu are focused, the dropdown menu remains visible. In order to do this, I need to save the "grandparent" as a variable, so I can modify its styles when the children are focused:

```
.mainNavigation__desktop__content {
  $mainNavigation: &; // save parent selector as variable
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fefefe;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  padding: 34px 120px 35px 120px;
  text-align: left;
  *:focus {
    // Access variable to make grandparent of child element visible
    $mainNavigation {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
      opacity: 1;
      visibility: visible;
      pointer-events: auto;
    }
  }
}
```

However, my site (shopify preview) fails to load whenever I try to save the parent selector (&) to a variable. If I change this variable to anything else, the site will load without any problem.

Is there something I'm missing? Am I unable to access the parent selector in this way? All the examples I've seen for saving the parent selector as a variable show this exact syntax.

Comment: You can't style a parent element based on a child element's `:focus` state in CSS or Sass. You can only style element A based on element B if (B contains A) or (B is a sibling of A and precedes A).

Comment: @Sean do you know if there's any workaround? Or should I just use raw CSS?

Comment: It's not possible in CSS either. That's just not how CSS works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create selectors like that with variables, you need to use interpolation:

```
#{$mainNavigation} {}
```

Either way, you can't style a parent based on focusing the children using this method, you may want to look at [focus-within](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within)

Comment: Thanks so much! I wasn't aware of the focus-within selector! The lack of interpolation was a typo on my part; the page still failed to load even if I removed that section of the code and only kept the part where I'm saving the parent selector to a variable. I'd still be really interested to know if there's a way I can save & to a variable.

Comment: You can save & to a variable in scss though? I do it all the time. Are you getting any compile errors? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/caching-current-selector-sass/